# Unit Test Directive Click Event Based On Scope Value

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a directive attribute, that passes a value and performs an action based on the value:

```
define(function () {
'use strict';

var myDirective = function ($rootScope, myFactory) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            _myValue : '=value'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', function() {
                if (scope._myValue === 'red') {
                    myFactory.red();
                }
                if (scope._myValue === 'green') {
                    myFactory.green();
                }
                if (scope._myValue === 'black') {
                    myFactory.black();
                }
            });
        }
    };
};

return ['$rootScope', 'myFactory', myDirective];
});
```

HTML:

```
<a my-directive  value="\'red\'"></a>
```

Unit Test:

```
define(['angular-mocks'], function () {
'use strict';

var angular = require('angular');

describe('<-- Directive Spec ------>', function () {

    var scope, $compile, element;

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('myApp'));

    beforeEach(inject(['$rootScope', '$compile', function (_$rootScope_, _$compile_) {
        scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
        $compile = _$compile_;

        var html = '<a my-directive  value="\'red\'"></a>';
        element = $compile(angular.element(html))(scope);
        scope.$digest();

    }]));

    it('should be red and call myFactory.red', function () {
        element.click();
    });
```

---

UPDATE:

```
define(['angular-mocks'], function () {
'use strict';

var angular = require('angular');

describe('<-- Directive Spec ------>', function () {

    var scope, $compile, element, myFactory;

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('myApp'));

    beforeEach(inject(['$rootScope', '$compile', function (_$rootScope_, _$compile_, _myFactory_) {
        scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
        $compile = _$compile_;

        var html = '<a my-directive  value="\'red\'"></a>';
        myFactory = _myFactory_;
        spyOn(myFactory , 'red');
        element = $compile(angular.element(html))(scope);
        scope.$digest();

    }]));

    it('should be red and call myFactory.red', function () {
        expect(myFactory.red).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

Tried the above and get error:

```
Error: spyOn could not find an object to spy upon for red()
```

Factory example:

```
define(['require', 'angular'], function (require, angular) {
    'use strict';

    var myFactory = function () {    

        return {
            red: function() {
                console.log('red');
            },
            green: function() {
                console.log('green');
            },
            black: function() {
                console.log('black');
            }
        };
    };

    return myFactory;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have added a spy just like this in the `beforeEach`:

```
spyOn(myFactory, 'red');
```

And then check if it has been called :

```
expect(myFactory.red).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Of course, you have to inject `myFactory`.

Comment: Thanks, nice solution. Do i have to define myFactory? Does the spy go before digest? After?

Comment: Declare a `myFactory` var just like as you did with ` scope`. Then, inject `_myFactory_` and affect it to the `myFactory` var : `var myFactory = _myFactory_`. That's it. Then, put the spy as soon as possible (before the `compile`.

Comment: Thanks, tried that, see above update. Seeing an error.

Comment: `slidingMenuFactory` should be `myFactory`.

Comment: Sorry, copied that from another SO thread, have updated to myFactory

Comment: Do i need a andCallThrough? Im using Jasmine 2

Comment: What does your factory look like? Is it perhaps an object you need to create with "new MyFactory()"..?

Comment: So the first problem was that beforeEach(inject(['$rootScope', '$compile', function (_$rootScope_, _$compile_, _myFactory_) { didnt have myFactory in the array... After adding that, new error is Expected spy red to have been called.

Comment: @AndyHasIt - added example of myFactory

Comment: You are working with a module loader. There are some steps to follow so that you can unit test your factory. Please have a look at : http://open.blogs.nytimes.com/2015/01/15/how-to-unit-test-a-requirejs-application/?_r=0 . By the way, it's out of scope of that question. Please post another thread and check my answer if it has suited your (first) needs.

Comment: @Zakaria - thanks for your help, raised here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35654818/unit-test-expect-spyon-not-found