# Unit Test Expect SpyOn Not Found

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a directive (restrict A) that handles an event click, and calls a service based on a value.

Directive:

```
define(function () {
'use strict';

var myDirective = function ($rootScope, myFactory) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            _myValue : '=value'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', function() {
                if (scope._myValue === 'red') {
                    myFactory.red();
                }
                if (scope._myValue === 'green') {
                    myFactory.green();
                }
                if (scope._myValue === 'black') {
                    myFactory.black();
                }
            });
        }
    };
};

return ['$rootScope', 'myFactory', myDirective];
});
```

Test:

```
define(['angular-mocks'], function () {
'use strict';

var angular = require('angular');

describe('<-- Directive Spec ------>', function () {

    var scope, $compile, element, myFactory;

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('myApp'));

    beforeEach(inject(function (_$rootScope_, _$compile_, _myFactory_) {
        scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
        $compile = _$compile_;
        var html = '<div><a my-directive  value="\'red\'"></a></div>';
        myFactory = _myFactory_;
        spyOn(myFactory , 'red').and.callThrough();
        element = $compile(angular.element(html))(scope);
        scope.$digest();

    }));

    it('should be red and call myFactory.red', function () {
        element.click();
        expect(myFactory.red).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

With the above, i get error:

```
Expected spy red to have been called.
```

Im using Jasmine 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are clicking the `<div>`, not the `<a>`, which has the directive and the event handler. Do:

```
element.find('a').click();
```

Or simply remove the `<div>` from the compiled HTML.

Comment: Doh! Thank you very much